# Problem with load Image via Glide from URL ("Failed to find any ModelLoaders for model")

Tags: android, image, android-glide

I got problem with load image from URL by Glide. URL is correct, already checked response via Postman. After setting up listener in Glide I got StackTree from onLoadFailed:

```
01-13 21:11:50.780 20972-21099/findbookproject.k.findbook E/GlideExecutor: Request threw uncaught throwable
    com.bumptech.glide.Registry$NoModelLoaderAvailableException: Failed to find any ModelLoaders for model: findbookproject.k.findbook.data.ImageLinks@b1e32bc
        at com.bumptech.glide.Registry.getModelLoaders(Registry.java:584)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeHelper.getLoadData(DecodeHelper.java:205)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeHelper.getCacheKeys(DecodeHelper.java:223)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.ResourceCacheGenerator.startNext(ResourceCacheGenerator.java:44)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:302)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:269)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:233)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:446)
```

Here is my Adapter and ViewHolder class:

```
public class FindAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FindAdapter.ViewHolder> 
{

    private List<Items> books = new ArrayList<>();

    public void updateBooks(List<Items> bookList){
        books.clear();
        books.addAll(bookList);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ViewHolder(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_anserw,parent,false)
        );

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.setup(books.get(position));
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return books.size();
    }


    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        @BindView(R.id.item_book_image)
        ImageView bookImage;

        @BindView(R.id.item_anserw_description)
        TextView bookDescription;

        @BindView(R.id.item_anserw_name)
        TextView bookName;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this,itemView);
        }

        void setup(Items item){
            Glide.with(itemView.getContext())
                    .load(item.getVolumeInfo().getImageLinks())
                    .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            Toast.makeText(itemView.getContext(),"failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            Toast.makeText(itemView.getContext(),"Load Complete",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            return false;
                        }
                    })
                    .into(bookImage)
            ;

            bookDescription.setText(item.volumeInfo.description);
            bookName.setText(item.volumeInfo.title);


        }


    }
}
```

And here's layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_book_image"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/standard_mar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/standard_mar"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/standard_mar"
        android:id="@+id/item_anserw_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:padding="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/item_book_image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="textView 1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/standard_mar"
        android:id="@+id/item_anserw_description"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView 2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/item_anserw_name"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/item_book_image"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:padding="16dp"


    />




</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I was using same Glide methodology some times ago in different application and was working just fine. Not sure in what problem lies. Last time wasn't need to implement ModelLoaders. Glide version 4.8.0

Comment: Are you sure `item.getVolumeInfo().getImageLinks()` is an url?

Comment: After your question i checked response for different kind of Image url I can get from getter getImageLinks available(fullsize, thumbnail, small thumbnail etc). Somehow am getting thumbnail with proper url but not for small thumbnail or fullsize. Probably there is some kind of problem with API i am currently using. Case pretty solved. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Want me to add an answer?

Comment: I think i will handle it,  but thx for asking mate :)